# How do i get the value of an attribute for all elements dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey there,
I have a Navigation Menu and my code looks like this..

```
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href = "#countries" >Countries</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#states" id="">States</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#cities">Cities</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#areas">Areas</a></li>
    </ul>
```

i would want to fetch all the attributes values dynamically depending on the user click for example if the user clicks on Countires it should fetch the value #countries, if the user clicks on states it should fetch the value #states and so on.

i am aware of the .attr() in jQuery. the functions only fetches the first element in the set of matched elements. no matter wherever i click it will fetch only #countries. i do not want to be this case.

i am using the following jquery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //when the user clicks on Navigation Menu call this function
    $('ul#nav li a').click(function(){
        //fetch the attribute value.
        $value = $('ul#nav li a').attr("href");
        alert($value);

        //Stop the default behaviour
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How do i fetch all the attribute value dynamically and store the value in different variable?

Comment: Don't forget to declare your local variables.

Comment: Also, why does the $value variable have a $ prefix? It's just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
var $value = $(this).attr('href');
```

Inside the click handler, the `this` value refers to the element that has been clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
$value = $('ul#nav li a').attr("href");
```

To this:

```
var $value = $(this).attr('href');
```

Or even just this:

```
var $value = this.getAttribute('href');
```

(Note that the implementation of `getAttribute` in IE6 and IE7 is broken.)

Comment: `this.href` won't do. It returns the fully qualified URL. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/UVefs/

Comment: @Šime Thanks for your edit. The beauty of using a tested JS framework is that someone else has already done most of the cross-browser testing.

Comment: thank you for the tip mark about .getAttribute() i am certainly going with .attr().. cheers!! :)